# Everything works perfectly but I get the warning: Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

Tags: php

I am getting this warning even though everything functions perfectly.

Here is the code snippet:

```
$selected_Id = isset($_GET["url"])?$_GET["url"]:""; 
// if no services selected, go to first service
$mysqliContent = new CustomMySqli();
if ($selected_Id=="") {
    $queryContent = "SELECT servicesID, ServiceUrl, title, content FROM services order by orderField asc LIMIT 1";
    $stmtContent = $mysqliContent->prepare($queryContent);
} else { 
$queryContent = "SELECT servicesID, ServiceUrl, title, content FROM services WHERE ServiceUrl = '$url'";
$stmtContent = $mysqliContent->prepare($queryContent);  
$stmtContent->bind_param('d',$selected_Id);
}
/* execute query */
$resultContent = $stmtContent->execute(); 

// bind results
$stmtContent->bind_result($idContent, $urlContent, $titleContent, $contentContent);
$contentContent = stripslashes($contentContent);

/* fetch values */ 
$stmtContent->fetch();
$selected_Id = $idContent;
/* close statement */
$stmtContent->close();
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the parameter in the query?

Comment: The error message is clear: your problem is that the **Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement** ... so fix that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
$queryContent = "SELECT servicesID, ServiceUrl, title, content FROM services WHERE ServiceUrl = ?";
```

Prepared statements replace all question marks with the variable(s) supplied to bind_param().